# Chrome O.S. : In tablet mode, switching from floating keyboard to normal keyboard is not working as expected

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-keypad, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

**Problem -**

In tablet mode of Chromebook, in an android app, if we switch from floating keyboard to normal on-screen keyboard in, the screen does not adjust and block the UI.

**Steps to reproduce the problem -**

1. Open an android application which has a user input field at the bottom of the screen.
2. Click on the input field. It will open an onscreen keyboard and adjust the input field above that keyboard.
3. Now switch to floating keyboard. It will again adjust the UI and put input filed at the bottom of the screen.
4. Again switch to a normal keyboard. This time screen is not adjusted itself and input filed get covered/blocked by keyboard.

**Expected behavior -** 
        The screen should be adjusted and the keyboard should not block.

**Tested on -** 
        Samsung Chromebook Pro - 7.1.1, Chrome OS Verison 73.0.3683.114